# Microsoft Excel Formula

Tags: excel, vba

Can some one recommend a reference for learning Excel for a programming minded person. I am looking for a less ummm squishy reference then the ones presented by a web search. All I could find was information for mouse monkeys.

I am looking for a syntax and function reference and information about using VBA. I also would appreciate a link to learning access for some one who knows SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Excel.

Press Alt-F11. (VBA editor opens).

Press F1. (VBA help opens)

Choose Excel VBA reference.

(And for the Access part of your question: I would suggest almost the same: have a look into Microsoft's original VBA docs which come together with the product, they are definitely for programmers, not for "mouse monkeys").

Comment: That's exactly what he asked for ;-)